# Computed column function that references another row?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am a bit new to SQL, and am having trouble turning this code into a a function I can use for a computed column. This works perfect as a select statement.

```
select (coalesce(a.samplevalue - (
    select b.samplevalue 
    from numericsamples b 
    where b.rowid = a.rowid - 1), a.samplevalue)) as Diff 
from dbo.NumericSamples a
```

This basically just subtracts the previous row value.

Comment: What RDBMS and version? Assuming SQL Server you can't (at least not as a `persisted` computed column anyway you could wrap it in a scalar UDF and use it in a non persisted computed column but performance will likely be poor)

Comment: I am using Sql server, I would like it to be a persisted computed column, as there is about  five million records. Any ideas for attacking this problem of subtracting previous row in a different way. I would really like  this to be computed as new data is being pushed into the database and as of right now I do not have control of the incoming data.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, good point, let's hope the OP enlightens us

Comment: @PatPav - What version of SQL Server? 2012 has `LAG` and `LEAD` that may be useful in not needing this persisted at all depending on how you are planning on using this.

Comment: Most likely after all the testing, I will be using sql server 2005 or 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would a `VIEW` with the following definition not be better for you?
Using `ISNULL()` instead of `COALESCE()` as I believe it will be very slightly faster.
I'm not certain that my JOIN criteria is correct though.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Answer]
WITH SCHEMABINDING -- !Please read up about SCHEMABINDING!
AS
SELECT   T1.rowid 
        ,Result = ISNULL(T1.samplevalue - T2.samplevalue, T1.samplevalue)
FROM dbo.NumericSamples T1
JOIN dbo.NumericSamples T2  ON T1.rowid - 1 = T2.rowid 
--  OR
--  JOIN dbo.NumericSamples T2  ON T1.rowid = T2.rowid -1
```

Regarding `ISNULL()` vs `COALESCE()` -
It seems that `ISNULL()` is faster in this instance

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#ISNULL') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ISNULL
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#COALESCE') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #COALESCE

DECLARE @StopW DATETIME = GETDATE()
SELECT   T1.rowid 
        ,Result = ISNULL(T1.samplevalue - T2.samplevalue, T1.samplevalue)
INTO #ISNULL
FROM dbo.NumericSamples T1
JOIN dbo.NumericSamples T2  ON T1.rowid - 1 = T2.rowid 

PRINT DATEDIFF(MS, @StopW, GETDATE())
SET @StopW = GETDATE()

SELECT   T1.rowid 
    ,Result = COALESCE(T1.samplevalue - T2.samplevalue, T1.samplevalue)
INTO #COALESCE
FROM dbo.NumericSamples T1
JOIN dbo.NumericSamples T2  ON T1.rowid - 1 = T2.rowid 

PRINT DATEDIFF(MS, @StopW, GETDATE())
```